# Close file in the end of procedure VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have code like below, I would like to open a file and not to close it up to end of procedure.

```
Workbooks.Open filename:=file1
' copy something

Windows(file2 & ".xlsm").Activate
'paste something
```

And here I would like to have make file1 still opened, here only activate, btw Windows(file1 & ".xlsm").Activate this line does not give expected result. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there any more code you could provide? What exactly is the error you are getting?

Comment: What is file1 & file2?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
dim wb as workbook
set wb = Workbooks.Open (file1)
wb.visible = true
' copy something

Windows(file2 & ".xlsm").Activate
'paste something
```